# Precision with opamp in transimpedance amplifier configuration with LED as photodiode

Tags: operational-amplifier, precision

I found this circuit in searching for a circuit that uses LED to measure absorbance

[image: Schematic]

What I want to ask is: in order to "accurate" the readings from \$ V_{out} \$, for example: assume that the current through LED is \$ -0.1 µA \$, \$ V_{R} = 10 kOhm \$,  then \$ V_{out} \$ should be \$ 1 V \$ but the actual reading is \$ 1.303 \$ for example. I know this is due to many parameters such as: devices, offset current, bias current, offset voltage, blah blah ...

I just wonder how can I reduce the error and obtain the result more accurately?

Comment: If you're using an LED as a photodetector, don't expect accurate results.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. What are CV and VA? And 1.003V instead of 1V is an error of 0.3%. Unless you are using resistors more accurate than 1%, you are lucky to get a reading that close to the theoretical value.

Comment: both CV and VA opamp is OP07 . 1.003 is just an example . Sorry for the unclear question . I just want to ask how can i get the result more accurately

Comment: What is "absorbance"?

Comment: @ThePhoton : i mean the absorbance of a sample respect to a certain wavelength

Comment: Sources of error in op-amp circuits is a large topic.

Comment: And how, exactly, do you know that your current is 100 nA? And discussions of bias currents at these levels as "blah blah" suggests that you have entirely the wrong attitude. Rejecting a discussion of your possible error sources at the same time you ask how to compensate for them is both arrogant and self-defeating, since it pretty much guarantees that nobody will take you seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You start with "how accurate do I need?" then move on to "How do I get it?"  Never start the second until you know the first.

The example you cite shows a *0.3% error*.  You can work for a decade without needing that sort of precision.

For this particular case, to get better than that, you would need to start with a very precise \$1.000M\Omega\$ resistor.  Then, you need an opamp with small bias voltages and currents.

Comment: "The example you cite shows a 0.3% error." Umm, no. 0.3/1.0 is 0.3, or 30%.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeastwh indulge me by peeking at the edit trail ;)

Answer (score 1):

> then Vout should be 1V but the actual reading is 1.003 for example .

that would be an ***extremely*** accurate reading. if that's indeed what you get.

> I just wonder how a real "accurate" readings could be obtained ?

through calibration mostly.

Answer (score 1):

There is real problem here:

> assume that the current through LED is −0.1µA, VR=10kOhm, then Vout
>   should be 1V but the actual reading is 1.303 for example.

Apparently you "assume" the current is 0.1 uA, but you measure the output voltage at 1.303.

Unless you *measure* the current as being 0.1 uA, there is no way to tell if it really is. Then you have no way to tell that the output is actually wrong.

I'd suggest building the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flSOtm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the critical parameter to consider is the input bias current current of the op amp. Make sure that it is on the order of 1 nA or less. Also fairly important is the input offset voltage. Since the nominal voltage across the resistor will be about 100 mV for an assumed LED current of 0.1 uA, you'll want an offset of 1 mV or less if you want 1% accuracy.

With this circuit, you can establish the actual current being provided. Only then can you start determining what your system error actually is.

Note that this circuit essentially does the same thing as the TIA you built for the first stage, and doesn't have the possible stability issues which make the feedback capacitor necessary. So why use a TIA? It's faster for large gains. The feedback capacitor compensates for the LED capacitance which will limit the follower circuit.